# How do I filter out issues that are in the backlog?

Tags: jira, backlog

Trying to have a query that filters out issues that are in the backlog.

This is a workflow status:
[image]

I tried `statusCategory != Backlog`
And it says: `The value 'Backlog' does not exist for the field 'statusCategory'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error that you are getting tells that `Backlog` isn't status category.
There are 3 status categories: `To do`, `In progress` and `Done`.
(You cannot change them as far as I know [[1](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-36241),[2]](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/How-do-I-add-or-edit-Jira-workflow-categories/qaq-p/528891))

It seems that you have status called `Backlog` and you can search issues by it like:
`status = Backlog`

Comment: So workflows I create myself are "status" not "statusCategory"?

Comment: @red888 'Backlog' on the picture you posted is 'status'. Your question is a bit weirdly phrased, but I believe the answer is yes.